# Django - avoid false records if the pk of a dynamic url is changed

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am designing an app where students can rate their teachers through a survey.

Basically what the app does is it generates a dynamic url for each teacher, for example:

- Teacher Mike : mywebsite.com/teacher/1
- Teacher Brian: mywebsite.com/teacher/2

The numbers correspond to the PK of each teacher. The student fills out the survey and when sending it, first validates in the database that the answers have not been sent previously (to avoid duplicates). In case the answer has already been saved before, a page is displayed where it says this.

Everything works fine, but there is a problem if the user (student) performs a strange action. When the student rates for example the  Teacher Mike :  the url that is generated is mywebsite.com/teacher/rate/1 and shows a template that says that the answer is saved. The problem comes here:

If the person at that time changed the number(pk) in the url, for example from 1 to 2, the app saves the teacher-1's answers in the teacher-2's record.

**clarification**: if the student is assigned teachers 1, 2 and 3 and changes the pk in the url to 5, there is no problem since the app detects that the student does not have permission to grade that teacher. The problem is if it is changed from 1 to 3, for example, since the student has permission to grade both students.

I know it's strange behavior. But I'd like to find a way to solve this.

The view for submitting the answers is this:

```
def send(request, user_pk):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/')
    else:
        #first look for the record not to exist in the DB to avoid duplicate records
        exist = Answers.objects.filter(name= request.user, teacher= user_pk ).exists()
        # if there is not then I proceed to create the record in the database
        if exist == False:
            for key, value in request.POST.items():
                if clave != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':
                    Answers.objects.create(question=int(clave), answer_to_question=int(valor), student = request.user,teacher = int(user_pk)) 
            #then I change a record in the table of my DB where the finished evaluations are stored, from false to true.  
            actual_state= State.objects.get(student__name = request.user, teacher = user_pk)
            actual_state.finished_evaluation = True
            actual_state.save()
            return render(request,"myapp\send.html") 
        else:
            return render(request,"myapp\error.html")
```

Comment: What would be the "correct" result if the student tries to post the form to a url for a different teacher? You could add a some token (similar to the csrf token) that contains a salted cryptographic hash of the accepted url for the form.

Comment: @ Håken Lid  The most important thing is that you are not allowed to keep that false record. In addition to this you could generate a url saying that what you are trying to do is an invalid action.

Comment: What do you mean by "false record"? Is there any differences between the forms for `/teacher/1/` and `/teacher/2/`? As long as you confirm that the student is permitted to submit a review for that teacher, then why does it matter how they do that? If there's no way to distingush a "false record" and a "true record", it seems that all submitted forms should be considered valid.

Comment: There are differences between the forms of each teacher, but I don't think this is key. Suppose there is no difference, and the survey only has one question: "Is he a good teacher?" If I change the pk in the url, I will record the teacher's rating 1 as if it were the teacher's rating 2.

Comment: And what's the problem with that? They would be able to do so anyway, wouldn't they? That said, it seems that adding a unique token in a hidden field in the form should protect you from this scenario. You could for example generate a token that would be unique to each teacher-student pair in this way: `hashlib.sha256(f'{student.id}{teacher.id}{settings.SECRET_KEY}'.decode()).hexdigest()`.

Comment: It's a possible solution, although I have to say that something advanced for my knowledge (I'm new). I had thought of a simpler solution such as after the student sends the answers the view removes the current POST object. But I'm not sure if it would be viable

Comment: HTTP is intended to be a stateless protocol. When you recieve a POST request, you should (ideally) be able to just process that in isolation. In practice you have to use "hacks" such as cookies, server side session objects and csrf tokens to prevent unauthorized access. In this case the simplest solution is to just accept that "trollers gonna troll". If a student is determined to submit dishonest reviews, there's no programming solution that can stop them from doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of worrying about the user changing the URL, I suggest that you add a check that the user is allowed to submit answers for that teacher.

For instance, if the `Teacher` model had a `many-to-many` field to `User`, then you could filter so that users could only submit answers for their teachers.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def send(request, user_pk):
    teacher = get_object_or_404(Teacher, students=request.user)
    exist = Answers.objects.filter(name= request.user, teacher=teacher).exists()
```

Note I've used the `login_required` decorator above so that you don't have to manually redirect users that are not logged-in.

Comment: What you suggest is already in the app (I didn't add it because I didn't think it was key to the question, I'm sorry.I'll edit the question.). If a student has for example assigned teachers 1, 2 and 3 and changes the pk of the url to 5 there is no problem since the app detects that the student doesn't have permission for this. The problem is the student change for example from 1 to 3, since the student has both teachers assigned to him/her

Comment: If the user has permission to grade teacher 3, then what is the problem if the user grades teacher 3 by meddling with URL that the form is submitted to?

Comment: the problem is not when the user changes `miweb/teacher/1` to `miweb/teacher/3`, as in this case it will only be redirected to the teacher's survey 3. The problem is if after sending the answers of the teacher-1's survey it changes the url from `miweb/teacher/rate/1` to `miweb/teacher/rate/3` as it will automatically record in the database the answers that the student gave for the teacher 1 also for the teacher 3.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your latest comment. I'm going to delete this answer because it doesn't address your updated question. I still think you're approaching this the wrong way. As long as your view validates that the user, answer, teacher combination is valid, I don't see the practical benefit of adding tokens to ensure that the form submission came from the correct page.

Comment: Let me make one last attempt to make myself understood. Let's say you're the student. You go to `www.website.com` and the page will show a template that says: "You must evaluate Professor Brian and Professor Amy". You click on Brian and this takes you to `www.website.com/teacher/1` where the survey appears. You fill out the survey and click on the "send" button where the `send` view is activated. Clicking on "send" activates the url `www.website.com/teacher/1/rates` and saves your answers about brian in the database , and displays a template that says "your answers have been saved"

Comment: At this very moment your browser displays the url `www.website.com/teacher/1/rates`, the template shows a message that says "your answers have been saved" and in the database is recorded the rating you give to `Professor Brian.`

If in this moment you modify the url `www.website.com/teacher/1/rates` to `www.website.com/teacher/3/rates` in your browser, the same scores you gave to `Professor Brian` will automatically be saved for `Professor Amy`. What's wrong, since you never evaluating Professor Amy, you just changed a number in the url.

Comment: No, if you change the URL to `www.website.com/teacher/3/rates` in your browser, then your browser will do a GET request to `www.website.com/teacher/3/rates`, which shouldn't save any scores. If the user is sophisticated enough to use the browser's development tools to submit the form to the wrong URL, then why is that a problem (as long as the user is allowed to save an answer for that question and teacher)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The error was mine because what was modified was the State table where it said who had already done the evaluation and not the answer table as such. Simply add to the code to modify the State table to validate that the request.Post existed.

Comment: Glad you figured out what the problem was :)